# Android Пустой экран

Tags: java, android, циклы, textview

Хочу написать очередной проект для корзины, вот код:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tw = findViewById(R.id.timer);
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        ++i;
        tw.setText(Integer.toString(i));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}



}
```

Хочу увидеть 0, затем 1, затем 2 и тд с интервалом в 1 секунду

[image]

Однако вижу это, то есть пустой экран

[image]

Как решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы усыпляете основной, UI поток приложения. В итоге система не успевает отрисовать интерфейс до следующего засыпания. Вам надо делать задержку в другом потоке. Для этого, например, можно вот такой код написать:

```
int i = 0;
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {              
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tw.setText(Integer.toString(i));
                i++;
            }
        });
    }
};
new Timer().schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: На самом деле виноват даже не Thread.sleep а бесконечный цикл `while(true)` в основном потоке.

Comment: @blind.falcon, хм... Наверное, вы правы)